# Gentle Intro to Haskell: " .... there is no single type that contains both 2 and 'b'." Can I not make such a type ?

Tags: scala, haskell

I am currently learning Haskell, so here are a beginner's questions:

What is meant by **single type** in the text below ?

Is single type a special Haskell term ? Does it mean atomic type here ?

Or does it mean that I can never make a list in Haskell in which I can put both `1` and `'c'` ?

I was thinking that a type is a set of values.

So I cannot define a type that contains `Char`s and `Int`s ?

What about algebraic data types ?

Something like: `data IntOrChar = In Int | Ch Char` ? (I guess that should work but I am confused what the author meant by that sentence.)

Btw, is that the only way to make a list in Haskell in which I can put both `Ints` and `Chars`? Or is there a more tricky way ?

A Scala analogy: in Scala it would be possible to write implicit conversions to a type that represents both `Int`s and `Char`s (like `IntOrChar`) and then it would be possible to put seemlessly `Int`s and `Char`s into `List[IntOrChar]`, is that not possible with Haskell ? Do I always have to explicitly wrap every `Int` or `Char` into `IntOrChar` if I want to put them into a list of `IntOrChar` ?

From [Gentle Intro to Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/goodies.html):

> Haskell also incorporates polymorphic types---types that are
>   universally quantified in some way over all types. Polymorphic type
>   expressions essentially describe families of types. For example,
>   (forall a)[a] is the family of types consisting of, for every type a,
>   the type of lists of a. Lists of integers (e.g. [1,2,3]), lists of
>   characters (['a','b','c']), even lists of lists of integers, etc., are
>   all members of this family. (Note, however, that [2,'b'] is not a
>   valid example, since there is no **single type** that contains both 2 and
>   'b'.)

Comment: Your `[IntOrChar]` would not be `[2, 'b']` but `[In 2, Ch 'b']`.

Comment: Yes, so I cannot make an union type?

Comment: No, `single type` is not a Haskell term. "Single" is a regular English word, meaning "only one; not one of several". `IntOrChar` *is* a union type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer.

In Haskell there are no implicit conversions. Also there are no union types - only disjoint unions(which are algebraic data types). So you can only write:

```
someList :: [IntOrChar]
someList = [In 1, Ch 'c']
```

### Longer and certainly not gentle answer.

**Note: This is a technique that's very rarely used. If you need it you're probably overcomplicating your API.**

There are however existential types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification, RankNTypes #-}
class IntOrChar a where
   intOrChar :: a -> Either Int Char

instance IntOrChar Int where
   intOrChar = Left

instance IntOrChar Char where
   intOrChar = Right 

data List = Nil
          | forall a. (IntOrChar a) => Cons a List

someList :: List
someList = (1 :: Int) `Cons` ('c' `Cons` Nil)
```

Here I have created a typeclass `IntOrChar` with only function `intOrChar`. This way you can convert anything of type `forall a. (IntOrChar a) => a` to `Either Int Char`.

And also a special kind of list that uses existential type in its second constructor.
Here type variable `a` is bound(with `forall`) at the constructor scope. Therefore every time
you use `Cons` you can pass anything of type `forall a. (IntOrChar a) => a` as a first argument. Consequently during a destruction(i.e. pattern matching) the first argument will
still be `forall a. (IntOrChar a) => a`. The only thing you can do with it is either pass it on or call `intOrChar` on it and convert it to `Either Int Char`.

```
withHead :: (forall a. (IntOrChar a) => a -> b) -> List -> Maybe b
withHead f Nil = Nothing
withHead f (Cons x _) = Just (f x)

intOrCharToString :: (IntOrChar a) => a -> String
intOrCharToString x = 
   case intOrChar of
    Left i -> show i
    Right c -> show c

someListHeadString :: Maybe String
someListHeadString = withHead intOrCharToString someList
```

Again note that you cannot write

```
{- Wont compile
safeHead :: IntOrChar a => List -> Maybe a
safeHead Nil = Nothing
safeHead (Cons x _) = Just x
-}

-- This will
safeHead2 :: List -> Maybe (Either Int Char)
safeHead2 Nil = Nothing
safeHead2 (Cons x _) = Just (intOrChar x)
```

`safeHead` will not work because you want a type of `IntOrChar a => Maybe a` with `a` bound at `safeHead` scope and `Just x` will have a type of `IntOrChar a1 => Maybe a1` with `a1` bound at `Cons` scope.

Comment: Interesting! So this is a little bit similar to Scala's implicit conversion as far as I can tell ?

Comment: @jhegedus Seems like it. For implicit conversion Scala looks up a function that can do a proper cast. Here (when creating `Cons`) Haskell looks up an instance of `IntOrChar` for the type of the first argument. This instance(in GHC implementation) is passed as a dictionary(paper with details: [Implementing Type Classes](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.127.8206&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) and then extracted during pattern matching. There might be differences with lookup rules though.

Comment: Also, we can abuse notation and write `instance Num Char where fromInteger i = head $ show i` so that we can write `length [1,'c']` = 2, but this is using overloaded numeric literals, and actually represents `length "1c". It doesn't really have an integer in a list with a character.

Answer (score 3):

In Scala there are types that include both `Int` and `Char` such as `AnyVal` and `Any`, which are both supertypes of `Char` and `Int`. In Haskell there is no such hierarchy, and all the basic types are disjoint.

You can create your own union types which describe the concept of 'either an `Int` or a `Char` (or you could use the built-in `Either` type), but there are no implicit conversions in Haskell to transparently convert an `Int` into an `IntOrChar`.

You could emulate the concept of 'Any' using [existential types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Existentially_quantified_types):

```
data AnyBox = forall a. (Show a, Hashable a) => AB a

heteroList :: [AnyBox]
heteroList = [AB (1::Int), AB 'b']

showWithHash :: AnyBox -> String
showWithHash (AB v) = show v ++ " - " ++ (show . hash) v

let strs = map showWithHash heteroList
```

Be aware that this pattern is [discouraged](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) however.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "all the basic types are disjoint". `undefined` is in every standard Haskell type.

Comment: @dfeuer It's reasonable to assert that `undefined :: Int` is not `undefined :: Char`. Haskell treats these as very different, in the sense that `undefined` is a polymorphic function, rather than a constant inhabiting multiple types.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the distinction that is being made here is that your algebraic data type `IntOrChar` is a "tagged union" - that is, when you have a value of type `IntOrChar` you will know if it is an `Int` or a `Char`.

By comparison consider this anonymous union definition (in C):

```
typedef union { char c; int i; } intorchar;
```

If you are given a value of type `intorchar` you don't know (apriori) which selector is valid. That's why most of the time the `union` constructor is used in conjunction with a `struct` to form a tagged-union construction:

```
typedef struct {
          int tag;
          union { char c; int i; } intorchar_u
} IntOrChar;
```

Here the `tag` field encodes which selector of the union is valid.

The other major use of the `union` constructor is to overlay two structures to get an efficient mapping between sub-structures. For example, this union is one way to efficiently access the individual bytes of a int (assuming 8-bit chars and 32-bit ints):

```
union { char b[4]; int i }
```

Now, to illustrate the main difference between "tagged unions" and "anonymous unions" consider how you go about defining a function on these types.

To define a function on an `IntOrChar` value (the tagged union) I claim you need to supply two functions - one which takes an `Int` (in the case that the value is an `Int`) and one which takes a `Char` (in case the value is a `Char`). Since the value is tagged with its type, it knows which of the two functions it should use.

If we let `F(a,b)` denote the set of functions from type `a` to type `b`, we have:

```
F(IntOrChar,b) = F(Int,b) \times F(Char,b)
```

where `\times` denotes the cross product.

As for the anonymous union `intorchar`, since a value doesn't encode anything bout its type the only functions which can be applied are those which are valid for both `Int` and `Char` values, i.e.:

```
F(intorchar,b) = F(Int,b) \cap F(Char,b)
```

where `\cap` denotes intersection.

In Haskell there is only one function (to my knowledge) which can be applied to both integers and chars, namely the identity function. So there's not much you could do with a list like `[2, 'b']` in Haskell. In other languages this intersection may not be empty, and then constructions like this make more sense.

To summarize, you can have integers and characters in the same list if you create a tagged-union, and in that case you have to tag each of the values which will make you list look like:

```
[ I 2, C 'b', ... ]
```

If you don't tag your values then you are creating something akin to an anonymous union, but since there aren't any (useful) functions which can be applied to both integers and chars there's not really anything you can do with that kind of union.

Comment: The identity function is not the only polymorphic function, or even the most polymorphic one. `undefined` can be used at *any* type, so in particular it can be used at type `a -> b`. Similarly, `\x -> undefined` can be used at type `a -> b`. Constant functions and sequence functions are a little less polymorphic, but not by much: `\x -> (3::Int)` has type `a -> Int`, and so does `\x -> seq x (3::Int)`, for example.